# In VB.NET is "Exit Sub" necessary or helpful?

Tags: vb.net, exit, subroutine

When using Sub's, if I'm not returning a value, is it necessary to use:

```
Public Sub whatever()
       ...
       Exit Sub
End Sub
```

instead of just

```
Public Sub whatever()
       ...
End Sub
```

Do I gain anything (memory, speed, etc.) by using "Exit"?

Does the Sub exit anyway when it is done even if I don't use the "Exit" statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this particular case `Exit Sub` is completely unnecessary.  It can be used there but is generally considered bad style.  The statement is necessary when you want to prematurely leave the method.  For example if you detect a specific condition is met and you don't want to execute the rest of the method

```
Public Sub Example() 
  If SomeCondition Then 
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Do other work
End Sub
```

Comment: Even then it's not necessary, because you can just use `Return` like in other languages.